# Help identifying type of LC oscillator

Tags: rf, oscillator, schematics

I am trying to understand the RF transmitter (Q1) part of this schematic:

[image: schematic]

(source: https://fccid.io/KUJCE9001/Schematics/Schematic-Diagram-171495.pdf)

What type of oscillator is it? Colpitts, Hartley, something else?

Some context: this is a ceiling fan remote control, range a few meters. According to FCC documents, it transmits at 299.6 MHz. The input (into R3) comes from a digital encoder chip SM5023RF (I believe equivalent to PT2262 - datasheet: http://www.princeton.com.tw/Portals/0/Product/PT2262_5.pdf) which is a simple 12-bit pulse-position modulated code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SE.EE! You will get more help if you include the schematic with your question rather than asking people to follow a link. There is a built in schematic editor you can use, and you can focus on the particular part of the circuit that you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

*c. Something else.*

It is not an oscillator but rather a tuned tank circuit with a 10~20mA current LED indicator for Tx.

I am guessing it is a low baud rate wireless remote using AM RF available for near-field remote controls.

The tank circuit serves to suppress harmonics like an inexpensive low frequency AM modulator.

Component ratios are critical but there is a tuned inductor.

It's hard to tell without values, but all the reactances are critical by the gain controlled by C feedback ratios and collector-emitter impedance ratio.

The input is a logic level perhaps a common low-frequency near-field communication frequency of a burst clock to indicate a binary level.

[image]

Comment: +1 my thoughts too.

Comment: You could probably do away with the tank circuit and just use a larger diameter coil or ferrite  if it wasn't for AM band *unintended radiation* from logic signals. But who cares about AM these days and it would go far compared to megawatt AM broadcasts

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I added some context (which confirms your suspicions about what the device does) to the original post, and an inline schematic.

I have some follow-up questions:
- do you think U1 directly outputs RF, and the transistor/LC circuit only filters out the harmonics? I was assuming that U1 only outputs ~kHz range binary code, and Q1 generates the RF
- I was under the impression that for oscillation you need a closed loop and >1 gain at the desired frequency. So I assumed Q1 is used as an amplifier and LC circuit as the bandpass. Is that correct?